# Como criar matrizes aleatórias invertíveis no R

Tags: r, array, números-aleatórios, mínimos-quadrados

Uma das formas de se encontrar o estimador utilizando o método de mínimos quadrados ordinários, é por meio da geração de matrizes aleatórias, dado pela fórmula:
`B = (X’ X)^-1 X’Y`

Onde `Y = a+bx+cw+u`, sendo `x` e `w` vetores aleatórios de tamanho 1000 e distribuição `N(1,2)`.

A matriz `X` possui 3 colunas, sendo a primeira 1 a segunda `x` e a terceira `w`, e 1000 linhas. Após a geração dessa matriz aleatória é preciso realizar um for para que esse procedimento seja repetido 1000 vezes. 
No entanto, como eu não garanti que o produto `(X' X)` gerasse uma matriz invertível, o for me deu 1000 resultados iguais, não variando assim o `x`, o `w` e o `y`.

Estou tentando realizar essa condição pelo if mas não estou obtendo sucesso. 
Gostaria de saber se há algum comando que me garanta que a matriz possua inversa.

Comment: Livia, voce poderia colocar o que você fez? Seria muito difícil a matriz não ter inversa usando números aleatórios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito qual foi o problema, mas é quase impossível `(X'X)` não ter inversa neste caso, pois você vai gerar 1000 números aleatórios e só tem 2 variáveis. Então acho que o problema deve ter ocorrido na hora de gerar os números aleatórios, talvez postando o código que você usou seja mais fácil ajudar.

De qualquer forma, segue um exemplo que vai gerar a matriz `X` com `(X'X)` tendo uma inversa (os comandos `set.seed` não são necessários, são somente para garantir que o exemplo seja reproduzível):

```
### gera o vetor da constante
c <- rep(1, 1000)

### gera 1000 observações de x ~ N(1,2)
set.seed(1)
x <-rnorm(1000, 1,2) 

### gera 1000 observações de w ~ N(1,2)
set.seed(2)
w <- rnorm(1000, 1, 2)

### construindo a matrix X
X = cbind(c,x,w)
```

Veja que `(X'X)` tem inversa:

```
solve(t(X)%*%X)
              c             x             w
c  0.0015068062 -2.163410e-04 -2.629055e-04
x -0.0002163410  2.341451e-04 -1.098703e-05
w -0.0002629055 -1.098703e-05  2.434495e-04
```

Calculando os betas para um exemplo (y = 10 + 5x + 2w + u):

```
### y = 10 + 5x + 2w + u, u~N(0,1)
set.seed(3)
y <- 10 + 5*x +2*w + rnorm(1000)

### estimando os coeficientes por OLS
B= solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%y
B
      [,1]
c 9.994012
x 5.019442
w 1.994124
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela atenção e pela explicação.                Como você disse, o problema não estava na criação das matrizes inversas, mas sim na sintaxe do comando for().      O seu exemplo foi muito esclarecedor para mim, obrigada novamente.

Comment: Por nada! Que bom que ajudou!